# Mission Control apps fail for Java 17.0.1 - why?

Tags: jmc, azul-zulu, java-17

Azul Mission Control 8.1.0.42 and Oracle's Java Mission Control apps 8.1.0 fail to work with Oracle's Java 17.0.1 jdk on MacOs Monterey 12.0.1 with M1 chip... And since I cannot file this issue in GitHub, maybe someone can give me a clue here.

Comment: That's a known issue, which is being fixed right now. A fix for M1 will be available soon.

Comment: Any tracking link? GitHub issue?